# Why does programming take so many words that are normally used in different meanings?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Words like head, tail, stack, tree, and map are all used in programming and learning both programming and english at once has been hard for me. Why is this?

Comment: Think of your own language, and how many terms have specific meanings only used in a specific technical, scientific, medical, legal, etc. context.  These terms are called **jargon** and they exist in every language.  They get created anytime someone uses a common metaphor to describe new structures, processes, and patterns.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it has no simple answer.  There is no reason for it -- it just *is*.  It's just human nature. not anything to do with learning English.

Comment: What’s the alternative? Make up names? All of the programming words you listed have a clear connection to an existing sense of the word so they’re easy to remember.

Comment: To talk about any concept, we need a name for it.  Metaphors are a source of names in every field.  Programmers are not confused by the jargon use of ‘tree’ because the woody kind of tree is rarely found in their offices.

Answer (score 2):

The words are all have multiple *senses*, and the meaning in programming follows one of the existing senses of the words.

- Head, meaning "the first or top part of something" is a standard meaning in English. We say the "the head of the queue" or talk about "Section headings" in a document.
- Tail similarly has the meaning of "the end of something"
- Stack means an "orderly pile". We can talk about a "stack of plates" or a "wood stack"
- Tree has an existing mathematical meaning of "branching structure. The idea of a "family tree", for example, goes back to 1300. Programmers are just using this meaning.
- Map has a mathematical sense of "A function between sets", this extends from the sense of "a detailed representation of something" which comes from the "drawing of the world"

The use of these words in programming is quite natural, as the programming sense only refines or extends an existing meaning of the word. As a learner, you may not know all the meanings of a word, and if your language doesn't use "head" to mean "the top part of something" you might find it odd. It is not odd if you know all the meanings of these words.

Comment: ... and much of the language of programming inherited its rules from the way mathematicians make up names for things, which can be very confusing until the concepts are understood ("one to one and onto", for example).  I'd only have a little quibble about "stack": it's not the ordering that makes it a stack, it's the fact you can access it only from one end (can't pull out the bottom plate/piece of wood.)

Comment: By ordered, I didn't mean "numbered", I meant "orderly" or "tidy"